# <Redirect/> returns a blank page - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Hey guys i'm trying to send a user to the home page using `<Redirect/>` from `react-router` when they have been successfully logged in . But no success until now . The timeout is working , but it sends me to a blank page and not to the `Home.js` . Any idea how this problem can be fixed ?

**Confirm.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'
import Route from 'react-router-dom/Route';

import Home from './HomePage'

class Confirm extends Component {


    state = {
        redirect: false
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.id = setTimeout(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }), 3000)
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        clearTimeout(this.id)
    }
    render() {
        // setTimeout(function(){alert('Hello!');},3000); 
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className='Confirm'>
                    <Route path='/confirm' render={
                        () => {
                            return this.state.redirect
                                ? <Redirect exact to="/" component={Home} />
                                : <div className='Success'>
                                    <h1>Confirmed Session</h1>
                                    <p>Okay you are good to go . Your session has started .</p>

                                </div>

                        }
                    } />
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
export default Confirm;
```

Comment: Rendering the `Redirect` component will only set the path to `/`, it will not render anything by itself. You still need a `<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />` somewhere else in your app.

Comment: Yep , this has done the trick . But now when it renders the Home it has the same BG with the `className = 'Success' `, because `<Route>` works only inside of the `<div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<Route />`'s need to live one next to the other:

root.js

```
<Router>
  <Switch>  
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/confirm" component={Confirm} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

confirm.js

```
if (this.state.redirect) {
  return <Redirect to="/" >
} else {
  <div>
    your confirm page
  </div>
}
```

Now you can redirect from one to the other, and the entire page should be replaced.

Also take a look at the `<Switch>` Component from the react-router library.

*EDIT:* [Redirect isn't expecting a component prop](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect)

Comment: ` 
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/confirm' render={
                    () => {
                        return this.state.redirect
                            ? <Redirect exact to="/" component={Home} />
                            : <div className='App'>
                                <h1>Confirmed Session</h1>
                                <p>Okay you are good to go . Your session has started .</p>
                      </div>
                    }
                } />
            </Switch>`

Comment: in order my ` <Redirect/>`  to work i have to return it with a state otherwise it doesn't but still i recieve the BG from the previous screen and not from the Home Page

Comment: Yes , this does the job . Cheers mate !